# Center selected item on scroll in listview xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

I want the selected item to be constantly in the center of the list, even when scrolling.

I can determine in which direction the scrolling is going by tracking the current index in the ItemAppearing event and trying to set the SelectedItem to the previous item at 3 positions, but this is very inaccurate and varies depending on the screen resolution. Also, if I add ScrollTo to center the current item, it just scrolls constantly until it reaches the last item.

This is my ListView in xaml

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="HoursList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Hours}"
    ItemAppearing="ListView_ItemAppearing_Hour">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And here is ItemAppearing handler

```
private void ListView_ItemAppearing_Hour(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
{
    HoursItemsList = new List<int>(ViewModel.Hours);
    var currentIdx = HoursItemsList.IndexOf((int)e.Item);

    if (currentIdx > CurrentHourIndex)
    {
        // Direction = "Up"
        currentIdx -= IndexModificator;
    }
    else
    {
        // Direction = "Down"
        currentIdx += IndexModificator;
    }

    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = currentIdx;
    //((ListView)sender).ScrollTo(e.Item, ScrollToPosition.Center, true);
    CurrentHourIndex = currentIdx;
}
```

This is similar to result I'm trying to achieve

[image: TimePicker]

Comment: It seems like a Picker Control.

Comment: I can’t use the picker because it opens a dialog window for the list, but I need to display this list on the page

Comment: Okey, have a look at this .https://github.com/softlion/WheelPicker-Samples#wheel-picker-for-xamarin-samples

Comment: I tried this component, but the problem is that it is written that it is free, but at startup it displays the Wheelpicker trial version dialog box, which cannot be hidden. It is also written in the window that the full version is on vapolia.fr, but on this site they only have SVG image control.

Comment: Got it, if have more good soluton will share here .